# AWS Lambda Unable to authenticate with EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a python script that is sitting in an EC2 instance and is scheduled to run once a day. to do this, I'm setting up an AWS lambda function to start the instance, SSH into it, and execute certain commands to run my python script. I'm using Paramiko for my ssh connection and the code works flawlessly on my own local PC, but once I invoke the function on the AWS, paramiko throws an error saying it can't authenticate. I'm not sure what else to do here and any help would greatly be appreciated.
Things I tried so far:

using DNS, public IP, and even private IP without any success

changing my EC2 instance security group to allow all incoming network over all protocol

setting up a vpc

My Lambda function:

```
import boto3
import time
import paramiko
from os import path

region = 'ca-central-1'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region)
    instance = ec2.Instance('instance_name')
    instance.start()

    s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region)
    bucket_name = 'my_bucket_name'
    key_name = 'key.pem'
    key_location = path.join('/tmp', key_name)
    s3.download_file(bucket_name, key_name, key_location)
    time.sleep(45)

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    privkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(key_location)
    ssh.connect(instance.public_dns_name, 22, username='ubuntu', pkey=privkey)

    #
    ## run the py script
    #   

    ssh.close()
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Authentication failed.",
  "errorType": "AuthenticationException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 23, in lambda_handler\n    ssh.connect(instance.public_dns_name, 22, username=ec2_username, pkey=privkey)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/paramiko/client.py\", line 446, in connect\n    passphrase,\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/paramiko/client.py\", line 764, in _auth\n    raise saved_exception\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/paramiko/client.py\", line 664, in _auth\n    self._transport.auth_publickey(username, pkey)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/paramiko/transport.py\", line 1580, in auth_publickey\n    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/paramiko/auth_handler.py\", line 250, in wait_for_response\n    raise e\n"
  ]
}
```

The weird thing is that I'm getting an authentication error but I'm using the correct public key for that instance.

Comment: Your stack trace doesn't match your posted code. Also, be aware of the features of [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html).

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the trace. I'm trying to keep it in an EC2-Lambda pair only. addition of new AWS services is a big headache that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Typical reasons include: it's the wrong private key, it's the wrong username, or the local key file has the [wrong permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder).

Comment: its none of the above, I have run the exact code on my local computer and it works. the pem file downloaded from S3 is correct too. Also, it is not a permission issue since I got the same output by downloading the pem file to memory and then feeding it to paramiko rather than saving it locally.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically using SSH to connect to an EC2 instance to run commands is quite open to failure.

Here's a few other options...

#### Startup Script

Since you want to run the commands immediately after starting the instance, simply put the commands into:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

Any script in that directory will automatically run *every time* that the instance starts up.

You could then `sudo shutdown now -h` the instance to shutdown when processing is finished.

See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

#### SSM Run Command

The [AWS Systems Manager Run Command - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) allows you to run commands on one or more Amazon EC2 instances. The command is executed by an Agent installed on the instance, so SSH connections are not required.

#### Amazon SQS Queue

If you are frequently triggering jobs on an Amazon EC2 instance, then a common architecture is:

- Send a message to an Amazon SQS queue
- A program on the instance is continually **polling** the SQS queue for a message
- When a message is found, it triggers processing of the message

This is good when lots of messages could arrive and the EC2 instance is continually running.